# Entity Framework check all queries?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, database-connection, crud

I am refactoring my project exceptions. Entity Framework is used in this project. I want to check the database connection before all operations on the database.

I think, I should write an overridden method in data access layer, which is run before all queries. This method will check connection and if there is a connection problem should throw a `DBConnectionException` -> (derived class)

How can I do this on DAL or context class?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help, for EF-6 you can try use DbCommandInterceptor

```
public class DbConnectionCheckInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
    {
        public override void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
             //check connection
        }

        public override void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
             //check connection
        }

        public override void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
             //check connection
        }
    }
```

Before starting the application

```
DbInterception.Add(new DbConnectionCheckInterceptor());
```

Comment: Thank you, but project includes entity framework 5.0